# How to track interesting questions?

Tags: discussion

I find many questions interesting, to me, but can see that they have no *special* value for the community. So I can't flag them as favorite.

How can I keep track of those?

Comment: Why can't you click the star under the question and add it to your [favorites](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4142984/gyro-gearloose?tab=favorites&sort=activity) which, well, tracks interesting questions that you've favorited?

Comment: Because it also marks the question as favorite, visible to others, in order to attract special attention. For example, thee is a question about maven. I don't know anything about maven, so I can't decide if the question is really of interest for anyone except me and the OP.

Comment: It doesn't attract any more attention unless someone starts digging into Data.SE.  It is a favorite, thats it.  Its a way of marking it of interest *to you* so that you can look at your favorites tab and see if things are updated or not.  FWIW, on sites where I've got delete votes, I've used the favorites to keep track of questions that I want to cast delete votes on after it closes. Nothing (other than a badge) comes from marking a question as a favorite.

Comment: No. Similar, but not what I have asked. Sorry to incur even more down-votes.

Comment: I'm kind of worried that none of those trying to help and answer do understand my question.

Comment: <small>And I'm even more disturbed that I earnd a batch for needig more than 10 comments to communicate </small>

Comment: If you want to "favourite" a question without using the built in "favourite" feature then you could just bookmark it in your browser. I think there is no need to avoid the feature though and your concern is misplaced.

Comment: As no one is concerned about an inflation of questions flagged as "favorite" I won't bother my browser with bookmarks but spam stackoverflow with my favorites instead.

Comment: Excuse me, but if I'm the only one that has this concern, the favorites button is spoiled by inflation anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click on the star below the vote count:

[image]

Then the question will appear in your favourites tab in you profile. You'll be able to see any changes (new answers etc.) there. There's no automatic notification for changes to your favourite questions though.

[image]

You can also click on the RSS feed for a question. It's at the bottom right of the page:

[image]

This will notify you of changes, but in your RSS reader, not Stack Overflow, and is private.

Comment: As far as I understand, questions flagged *by me* as favorite will be seen by other users as "favorite". I want exactly to avoid that.

Comment: @GyroGearloose You forgot to mention that in your question.

Comment: That's what I wrote: " 0 down vote favorite
 

I find many questions interesting, to me, but can see that they have no special value for the community. So I can't flag them as favorite.

How can I keep track of those?
"

Comment: OK, it looks like I asked my question based on the false premiss that marking a question as "favorite" would be a means to attract special attention to that question. I choose this answer here because it also mentions RSS feed.

Answer (score 0):

You keep track of them by marking them as favourite.

They become *your* favourite, not something for the wider community.

Everyone can see the number of people who have marked the question as favourite, but only you can track your favourites through your profile.

Comment: So why can I see questions marked as favorite that I have never visited?

Comment: I've added that into the answer.

Comment: As far as I understand, marking a question favorite is intended to draw extra community attention to that question. In some cases, I don't want do do that because I think the question is not of special interest for the community.

Comment: @GyroGearloose it isn't intended to draw extra community attention. It is shown for information reasons only - nothing special happens to the question when it is marked as a favourite by users.

Comment: To make it more clear, the intention is **not** to hide my interests from the community, but to avoid kinda spam.

Comment: @GyroGearloose it isn't spam. This is exactly why favourite questions exist. If you don't want to use this feature, use your browsers bookmarks instead. Those are your options..

Comment: I could swear any oath that I have read somewhere here that the favorite button is to attract additional attention. But I can't find it any more. (Maybe I've been shifted to a parallel universe in a StarTrek like fashion ;-)

Comment: I don't understand why you think it is spam.  Do you think you might be thought of as spamming or do you think you may attract spam?

Comment: If, my false premiss was true, that a click on favorite is to attract more attention to a question, then seeing nearly all questions flagged as favorite would debase the value of a favorite flag (in the sense of attracting attention). It would be some kind of inflation.