# Flag a question to track updates

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

*note*  the vast majority of my stack overflow usage is on a mobile phone...

I'd really like to have the ability to 'track' some questions sometimes, because I've read it, and can see how the answer could benefit me, or sometimes attempted to solve it and failed.

In these scenarios it'd be really cool to be able to flag it and get notifications if someone has answered, or commented on the 'thread' (it's not quite a thread, feel free to edit the question if you have a better label for it).

I did do a brief search but if this has been requested / suggested before it didn't jump out at me, is it already in place? Or should I just use an app / Google bookmarks?

Comment: There's a Chrome Extension that does that - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stack-exchange-post-watch/kdjoaglbdcmgbmiahlkkhkkefncejmmm?hl=en

Comment: @paulie_d that's pretty cool, but I really want it on my phone :-) and ideally I'd be able to flag it from my phone and then have it tracked on PC too. It only appears to be available on PC - I'm not missing anything stupid am I?

Comment: You can always mark the question as one of your [favourites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work).

Comment: Pretty sure this is a dupe and has been declined before. - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276408/how-to-track-interesting-questions

Comment: @pualie is there an argument that I specifically want this in Mobile a distinguishing feature? I'm just asking, I don't mind deleting the question but as I say, I struggled to find it so if I leave it may help someone else...?

Comment: I have also wanted this feature, which is not served by favoriting.

Comment: This was brought up in the recent blogpost as a feature they are looking to implement (see the "Increase user engagement" section). https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/02/25/sharing-our-first-quarter-2020-community-roadmap/?cb=1